# Generating TIN from features in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, 3d-analyst, tin, surface

I am changing surface in some parts of area I use for project. To do that I draw polygons and add elevation to vertices using "`Interpolate shape`". Then I create TIN for edited parts of terrain. Next, I change TIN to raster and update terrain with my changes.

Unfortunately the tool "`Create TIN`" is not generating TIN model for all polygons from the input layer, there are some random gaps in some parts.

Does somebody know what can be the reason of that? Maybe there is a rule I did not hear about.

Edit:

[image]

Above you can see polygon which was used for TIN generation, then in the middle is TIN made with the use of polylines and polygons (polygons without capturing Z-value). On the top is another TIN generated just with the use of polygon (Height Field: Shape.Z, SF Type: Soft_Clip). Here looks like the TIN located on the top looks fine, but not all areas look like that.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of the input/output and maybe the tool parameters?

Comment: Convert polygons to polylines first.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. After converting polygons to polylines the result was even worse.

Comment: Does somebody know what to do to solve this problem? Do you think that's the fault of software?